# Hibernate connection parameters

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

Does Hibernate support connection 'parameters'? I'm new to Hibernate, but I notice that ConnectionProvider.getConnection() does not support any arguments.

Namely, I'm trying to implement a connection strategy (this for testing purposes) where a connection is selected (to be provided) based on certain arguments passed in during runtime (these can be different between calls). Does Hibernate even support such a thing? (i.e., something like getConnection(<+certain connection selection criteria/arguments>)?)

Comment: Short answer: Yes it does. More info: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc

Comment: Those look like options that must be specified before launching Hibernate. I'm looking for something like, "getConnection(key.for.connection-x) return connection-x", "getConnection(key.for.connection-y) return connection-y", dynamically at runtime after Hibernate has been launched.



Is such a connection strategy supported (at some level)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)

Essentially the connection provider SPI that will return a *specific connection* for a given key...